# Set host time from within docker container

Tags: rest, docker, time

How can I set the system host time from inside a docker container?

My goal is to expose a very simple REST API that I can use to set the system host time. The REST service will run inside the container.

Comment: That's probably not possible, and sounds like a really bad idea.  Time is an essential component to things like authentication.  One bad request sent to this API and poof - your machine could be inaccessible.

Comment: See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/824631/how-to-set-system-time-dynamically-in-a-docker-container

Comment: @MattJohnson agreed. How about something less harmless like setting the timezone of the host? This is common action.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/683651/100701

Answer (score 1):

By default Docker container doesn't allow access to system clock of the host.

However, if after careful consideration you're fine with your container having access to this capability, you can explicitly allow this capability on Linux using "--cap-add=SYS_TIME" option of "docker run" command when creating you container:

```
# docker run --cap-add=SYS_TIME -d --name teamcity-server-instance -v /opt/teamcity/data:/data/teamcity_server/datadir -v /opt/teamcity/logs:/opt/teamcity/logs -p 80:8111 jetbrains/teamcity-server
```

Then, you can change the time from inside the running container:

```
# docker exec -it teamcity-server-instance /bin/bash
# date +%T -s "15:03:00"
15:03:00
#
```

Reference documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities